# How to use specific custom objectMapper/JsonSerializer for specific requestMapping

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I know thar Jackson allow us to use custom serializer for specific domain/entity/modle, like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public class SimpleDomain {

}
```

And, is there any idea to specify custom serializer for some requestMapping,
(only for the specific requestMapping(that method), not to set global objectMapper.) like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "hello") 
@JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = NullToEmptyStrSerializer.class)
public @ResponseBody
Object get() {
    return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("aa", null);
        put("bb", "");
    }};
}
```

I execute the code above, it returns:

```
{
    "aa": null,
    "bb": ""
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "aa": "",
    "bb": ""
}
```

which exactly i wanted.

---

NullToEmptyStrSerializer :

```
public class NullToEmptyStrSerializer extends JsonSerializer {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

---

Or, can i get HttpServletRequest in NullToEmptyStrSerializer, if yes, i can filter in NullToEmptyStrSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it out by myself.
I realized this point:

> Or, can i get HttpServletRequest in NullToEmptyStrSerializer, if yes, i can filter in NullToEmptyStrSerializer.

---

### My purpose :

Custom convert `null` to `""` for specific Url(`RequestMapping`)

---

### My solution :

1. Define a bean to keep `ApplicationContext` storing in a static field, also, a static getter:

   ```
   @Component
   public class ContextHolder {
       private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

       @Resource
       public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
           ContextHolder.applicationContext = applicationContext;
       }

       public static ApplicationContext get(){
           return applicationContext;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define a bean below, this bean will create for every request, thus, i store `ServletRequest` in this bean.

   ```
   @Component("servletRequestHolder")
   @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
   public class ServletRequestHolder {

       @Resource
       private HttpServletRequest request;

       public HttpServletRequest getRequest(){
          return request;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then, a serializer is needed.

   ```
   public class NullToEmptyStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer.None {

       public static List<String> convertUrls = new ArrayList<String>(){{
           add("/hello");
       }};

       @Override
       public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
           HttpServletRequest request = ContextHolder.get().getBean(ServletRequestHolder.class).getRequest();
           if (request != null) {
               String currentUrl = request.getRequestURI();
               boolean match = convertUrls.contains(currentUrl);
               if (match) {
                   gen.writeString("");
               } else {
                   gen.writeObject(null);
               }
           } else {
               gen.writeObject(null);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the Serializer to objectMapper:

   ```
   DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
   sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullToEmptyStringSerializer()); 
   objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);
   ```
5. Finally, test it :

   ```
   @GetMapping({"hello", "hello1"})
   public Object get() {
       return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
           put("a", null);
           put("b", "");
       }};
   }
   ```

   In case of requesting `localhost:20000/hello`, the client receive:

   ```
   {
     "aa": "",
     "bb": ""
   }
   ```

   And for requesting `localhost:20000/hello1`, the client receive:

   ```
   {
     "aa": null,
     "bb": ""
   }
   ```

---

Answer (score 0):

It may be a known limitation (`@JsonSerialize` with `nullUsing` option not working for `String` properties) and reported in this [github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/33).

It is scheduled to be released in `jackson 2.9.3 and 2.8.11`.

> Fix will be in 2.9.3 but I also back-ported it in 2.8 branch in case
>   2.8.11 might be released at some point.